# Non-linear equation solving Sympy Python for hydraulics - Need resolve TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

Tags: python, sympy, solver, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to write a piece of python script to automate a quite time consuming task in some hydraulics problems, that occur in civil engineering.

The equation is from Colebrook-White, and is the following:

I have written the following code:

```
from math  import *
from sympy import *

e    = 0.2
d    = 0.2
v    = 0.00000131
q    = 10
s    = ( pi * d ** 2 ) / 4
u    = q / s
re   = u * d / v

lamb = symbols( 'lamb' )

solve(   1 / sqrt( lamb )                               \
       + 2 * log10(   e / ( 3.7 * d )                   \
                    + 2.51 / ( re * sqrt( lamb ) )      \
                  ),                                    \
         lamb                                           \
     )
```

But it gives the error:

```
   File "hg.py", line 12, in <module>
   solve(1/sqrt(lamb) + 2*log10(k/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(re*sqrt(lamb))),lamb)
   File "/home/luis/Documents/sympy/sympy/core/expr.py", line 211, in __float__
   raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
   TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

I couldn't post a picture of how the equation looks, as im new.

Since **`sqrt(lambda)`** is in both sides of the equation, I think it has to be solved by an iterative method, but I don't know how to do it... On my calculator (TI-Voyage 200) I usually use **`nSolve()`** and it does the job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you always can post a link to the Eqn. picture and I can upload it to your post, ok?

Comment: hi, thanks but i have solved it meanwhile! thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using `log10` instead of **`log( expr, 10 )`**. Correcting that and using bisection with **`nsolve`** works:

```
>>> eq = 1/sqrt(lamb) + 2*log(e/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(re*sqrt(lamb)), 10)
>>> nsolve(eq,lamb, (.1, 1.1), method='bisect')
mpf('0.77434599870454337')
```

See `help( mpmath.findroot )` for other solver options besides bisect.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do `from math import *`. This is munging up your namespace with functions from the math module, which don't work with SymPy expressions (they only work with floats). In this case, `log10` comes from math. Just do `from sympy import *`, or better, if you are writing a script, import everything you use explicitly.  The SymPy equivalent of `log10(x)` is `log(x, 10)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I have tried edited the imports, to import only the necessary, and tried this code now, but it still gives an error...

the code:
`solve(1/sqrt(l)+2*log(k/(3.7*d)+2.51(re*sqrt(l)),10),l)`

the error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Comment: You forgot a `*`. It should be `2.51*(re*sqrt(l))` not `2.51(re*sqrt(l))`.

Comment: thanks for spotting that error, but in fact it should be a / instead of * (my mistake). Unfortunately this doesn't affect the problem... It still gives the error: <br> `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sympy/core/expr.py", line 211, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!
With your help, together with other threads here on stackoverflow, I have been able to solve the problem.

This is my final, solved, code:

```
def f(x):
    return (-2*numpy.log10((2.51/(Re*numpy.sqrt(x))) + (k/(3.7*d))) - 1.0/numpy.sqrt(x))

lamb = float(fsolve(f, 0.02))
print "Lambda = %f " % lamb
```